# Incorrect RecyclerView item's height when scrolling is disabled

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My target is to be possible to get currently selected item positioned in the center of the RecyclerView and at the same time disable ability to scroll by the user (I want to do that only via my code).

To do so, I've added large top and bottom padding, so I can scroll the first and last items to the center (vertically). I've also added `clipToPadding="false"` to get scrolling working like described above.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/playRecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="290dp"
    android:paddingBottom="290dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"/>
```

The value of `290` is just an example, it should of course differ depending on screen size.
I've isolated my issue with following code:

Activity is the simplest possible (the only method):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recycler_activity);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.playRecyclerView);
    adapter = new TestAdapter();
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

`TestAdapter` is also very simple, and actually probably not important here, so I'll skip this code.

Item's layout xml is a `RelativeLayout` with single `TextView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/list_item_bg">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/taskListItem_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Final result look and works the way I want.

[image]

But when I disable scrolling by overriding `LinearLayoutManager` like this:

```
public class TestLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

    public TestLayoutManager(Context context) {
        super(context, VERTICAL, false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canScrollVertically() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I get incorrect rendering of items:

[image]

As I've noticed, that this height is equal to

```
itemHeight =  recyclerViewHeight - (TopPaddding + BottomPadding)
```

because when I set `clipToPadding=true` on RecyclerView, then I get such a view:

[image]

The item's height is cut in the same way.

Is it possible to make it work somehow?

Comment: you might be looking for this widget ? [link](https://github.com/yizeliang/WheelSelector)

Comment: @Du.Fantasy I don't know, it doesn't have any documentation. Just few words in Chinese. It looks more like a picker then a list. I've found other package that looks more promising, but still I would like to know, what's going on here in my code. :)

Comment: `canScrollVertically()` seems to be used to measure the child views and the logic is different depending upon the return value. Try setting your padding to something much less than 290dp in your `RecyclerView` to see if that makes a difference - I think that it will. Why it does would be the next question.

Comment: @Cheticamp yes, it does make a difference. As I said in my question `itemHeight =  recyclerViewHeight - (TopPaddding + BottomPadding)`. But why it takes paddings into calculation, when they may not be visible since RecyclerView has set `clipToPadding=false`

Answer (score 2):

Fixed height issue with code by override onLayoutChildren to detect layout start and onLayoutCompleted to detect layout completion.

```
public class ScrollBlockingLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {
    private boolean isInLayout = false;

    public ScrollBlockingLayoutManager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canScrollVertically() {
        //Similarly you can customize "canScrollHorizontally()" for managing horizontal scroll
        return isInLayout || (mAdapter.scrollEnabled && super.canScrollVertically());
    }

    @Override
    public void onLayoutChildren(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onLayoutChildren" + state.toString());
        isInLayout = true;
        super.onLayoutChildren(recycler, state);

    }

    @Override
    public void onLayoutCompleted(RecyclerView.State state) {
        super.onLayoutCompleted(state);
        Log.e(TAG, "onLayoutCompleted" + state.toString());
        isInLayout = false;

        //mCanScroll = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update: Alternate approaches added.**

My guess is that `clipToPadding=false` is negated by making the `RecyclerView` non-scrollable. Try the following to allow for proper layout and to disable scrolling at the very end. If I understand what you are trying to do, this should work.

```
public class TestLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {
    boolean mCanScroll = true;

    public TestLayoutManager(Context context) {
        super(context, VERTICAL, false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canScrollVertically() {
        return super.canScrollVertically() && mCanScroll;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLayoutCompleted(RecyclerView.State state) {
        super.onLayoutCompleted(state);
        mCanScroll = false;
    }
}
```

---

The above approach works on API 24 but not on 23 and, presumably, not on API <23 (see comments). The following outlines alternate approaches.

The `RecyclerView` code is such that you are losing the effect of `clipToPadding=false`. This is because the `RecyclerView` is being treated as a non-scrollable and the padding is honored in determining the maximum size of your item layout which becomes zero since the padding is so large in camparison to the screen size. (`int size = Math.max(0, parentSize - padding)` in `getChildMeasureSpec()`). See [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v7/recyclerview/src/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.java).

One way around this is to set the `RelativeLayout` in your item layout to be a fixed quantity if you know or can determine what it should be - this fixed quantity should be honored before the padding.

Another way is to flip the approach to let the layout manager see the `RecyclerView` as scrollable so the `RecyclerView` lays out as expected. To inhibit scrolling add a transparent overlay on the `RecyclerView` that intercepts the touch events. This overlay can be set to `visibility="gone"` to enable scrolling again.

Setting the response to `canScrollVertically()` to false seems to be the accepted way to prevent scrolling on a `RecyclerView`. I think that this works when the padding is much smaller than the screen size which would usually be the case but fails when the padding squeezes out available space when it is extra-large.

Comment: Well, yes and no. Setting `mCanScroll` to `false` in `onLayoutCompleted` doesn't help, but I've tried to set it later from outside on some other event like "onClick" and it indeed helps. So it may be a good way to go, but I need to find an event that is triggered later than `onLayoutCompleted`.

Comment: If `canScrollVertically()` returns `true` during the layout, as it normally does, you should be getting a good display. `canScrollVertically()` should only start returning `false` after the layout is completed.

Comment: Yes, I understand. It just seems that `onLayoutCompleted` is still too soon. ;-)

Comment: Something else must be going on then. I have been able to reproduce your issue using mostly the code you gave and this solution works as stated. I don't know what layout occurs after `onLayoutCompleted` that would cause problems.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share your working code via Github etc? I would like to compare it in details with mine.

Comment: The code is available [here](https://github.com/Cheticamp/Incorrect-recyclerview-height). I included the manifest and Gradle files, although they are just the standard ones.

Comment: After some investigation with your and mine code, I've found that your fix works when I'm running it on virtual device with API 24, but not working when it's API 23.

Comment: It looks like `onLayoutCompleted()` was added sometime after API 23 (version 23.0.1) since I don't see it in the source - useful, but not in this case I would say. I also see where the layout code you are hitting has been modified between API 23 and 25. I wonder if the technique you are trying to use worked OK with earlier versions but has been broken.